# How to split up compose file into multiple yaml files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

i currently have the following broken `docker-compose.yaml` file with a lot of services that depend on each other.
the volumes, secrets, and networks tags take a lot of lines. so i thought i would export them into multiple files.

here is what i did:

```
# volumes.yaml
x-volumes: &volumes
  driver: local
  driver_opts:
    type: bind
    o: bind
    device: /data/${{str}}


vol1:
  <<: *volumes
  str: bla1
vol2:
  <<: *volumes
  str: bla2
```

and for the networks:

```
# networks.yaml
nginx:
DLNA:
  driver: macvlan
  driver_opts:
    parent: eth0
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 192.168.178.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.178.1
        ip_range: 192.168.178.250/32
vpn_apps:
  driver: bridge
  driver_opts:
    com.docker.network.bridge.name: "docker-apps"
    com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: "true"
    com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc: "true"
    com.docker.network.driver.mtu: "1500"
  ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
      - subnet: 172.21.0.0/16
        gateway: 172.21.0.1
```

and for secrets i did something similiar:

```
# secrets.yaml
sec1:
  file: /opt/secrets/sec1
sec2:
  file: /opt/secrets/sec2
```

then in my `main.yaml`:

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  <<: ./volumes.yaml
networks: 
  <<: ./networks.yaml
secrets:
  <<: ./secrets.yaml
services:
  portainer:
    image: *images.portainer
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - vol1: /some/path
      - vol2: /some/path2
    networks:
      - nginx
    secrets: 
      - sec1
      - sec2
```

I'm getting the error: "yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value”.

How can I externalize the network, volumes, and secrets into different files?

Comment: Maybe you could extend or merge: https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/ , https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/ ,  or split your services and then use include https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/include/

Comment: Can you strip it down, so that you can see where the problem occurs?

Comment: The syntax `<<: ./volumes.yaml` is simply invalid: YAML aliases can only refer to anchors defined in the same file; they're not designed to import data from other files.

Comment: Can you restructure your application to not require either of these blocks?  Compose provides a `default` network automatically which will work just fine for most applications; multiple programs writing the same files can be tricky and avoiding file sharing in general is usually a good practice.